# facebook graph android sdk - under what circumstance will server response be null?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

sometimes randomly a few of my users are getting null values from facebook graph request.  but the only thing im requesting from the user is a email address ?  lets say the usr did not have a email address but used a phone number to register with facebook. then still why would the raw server response be null.  For most of my users its working. anyway, let me show you what my graph request looks like to shed some light:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                           token,
                           new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                               @Override
                               public void onCompleted(JSONObject userInfo, GraphResponse response) {
                                   if (userInfo == null)
                                       Crashlytics.log("facebook graph info null:" + response.getRawResponse());
                                   String email = "";
                                   try {
                                       email = userInfo.getString("email");
                                   } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                       e1.printStackTrace();
                                       /* sometimes i end up in this catch block and the rawResponse object is null
                                   }
                                   presenter.presentPasswordPrompt(task, email, credential);
                               }

                           });

                   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                   parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                   request.setParameters(parameters);
                   request.executeAsync();
```

as you can see i am printing out a log when the user info is null but the value from response.getRawResponse() is null itself so i cant figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Try to get more info with Troubleshooting: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/#userdata-troubleshooting

Comment: is there anyway i can capture those logs. i rather send them to crashlytics so i can view them from the fabric dashboard.  because its a random issue i can not reproduce it so loggin to my local machine wont work. i want to record the log when user actually fails the graph.